# Method not printing/returning

Tags: java, methods, println

I'm having a problem with one of my methods. I've checked it over and over again and I can't seem to find anything wrong. The problem that I have is that the method does not print within the console upon calling it. I think it might be related to the Scanner in the method.

The code for the method is:

```
public String cpuGuess() throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner fileRead = new Scanner(myGuesses);
        int line = rand.nextInt(99-1)+1;
        for(int i = 0; i <= line; i++){
            Guess = fileRead.next();
        }
        fileRead.close();
        CPUGuess = Guess;
        if(Arrays.asList(super.used).contains(CPUGuess)){
            System.out.println(cpu.cpuGuess());
        }
        else{
            StringBuffer hiddenBuff = new StringBuffer(hidden);
            for (int t = 0; t < phrase.length(); )
                if (CPUGuess == Character.valueOf(phrase.charAt(t)).toString()){
                    count++;
                }
            if (phrase.contains(CPUGuess)){
                ArrayList<Integer> indicies = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int index = phrase.indexOf(CPUGuess.toString()); index >= 0; index = phrase.indexOf(CPUGuess.toString(), index + 1)){
                    indicies.add(index);
                }
                int[] index = new int[indicies.size()];
                for(int i = 0; i < indicies.size(); i++) {
                    index[i] = indicies.get(i);
                }
                for (int n = 0; n < index.length; n++){
                    hiddenBuff.setCharAt(index[n], CPUGuess.charAt(0));
                }
                hidden = hiddenBuff.toString();
                status = "Correct";
            }
            else if (!phrase.contains(CPUGuess)){
                System.out.println("Sorry, no " + Guess + "'s");
                System.out.println("Human, you're up!");
            }
            super.used.add(CPUGuess.charAt(0));
        }
        System.out.println(count + " " + CPUGuess + "s");
        count = 0;
        return hidden;
    }
```

I call the method in the main class under the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("WHEEL... OF... FORTUNE!!!!");
    System.out.println(board.phraseGenerate());
    System.out.println(cpu.cpuGuess());
}
```

Please note that the cpu object has already been constructed and board.phraseGenerate creates both hidden and phrase.

Thank you for your help and please don't be condescending, I'm relatively new at this and I've seen a lot of post get discouraging feedback.

Comment: Do you get **"WHEEL... OF... FORTUNE!!!!"** in the console log when you run your code?

Comment: Yep here is an example of the console

Comment: WHEEL... OF... FORTUNE!!!!
S T A R   W A R S
_ _ _ _   _ _ _ _

Comment: Which print statements are you expecting to print but, does not print in this method?

Comment: WHEEL... OF... FORTUNE!!!!  (/n)
S T A R   W A R S  (/n)
_ _ _ _   _ _ _ _         (I added /n to show that its printed on the next line)

Comment: Did you try running through debugger?

Comment: it should always execute the last block of code

Comment: where its says return hidden

Comment: @L0rDvAd3r_9 you sure you are not missing a **{** after your for loop in that method? I don't know why you are not incrementing t in that for loop but, you are definitely missing the opening bracket.

Comment: @Raf yep thats definitely a problem. I can't believe I missed that

Comment: @Raf that was the issue thank you for your kind assistance

Comment: This loop will never end `for (int t = 0; t < phrase.length(); )` because it's missing a `t++`.

Comment: @L0rDvAd3r_9 you are welcome, if the answer helped then you have the option to mark it as **accepted**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, you seem to be missing an opening curly braces after your for loop as shown below:

```
 for (int t = 0; t < phrase.length(); )
```

which should be

```
 for (int t = 0; t < phrase.length(); ) { }
```

The above causes the print statement to be skipped. Don't forget that you are skipping the third part of the loop (the increment) as I mentioned in my comment. Not sure whether that is how your code is supposed to work or you have to add a t++ there as shown below:

```
//not sure if you forgot t++ or that's how it is supposed to work
for (int t = 0; t < phrase.length(); t++) { }
```

Comment: The problem is the missing `t++`, not the braces. It'll work fine without the braces.

Comment: With those braces, the loop does nothing, so your suggestion essentially is to just delete the loop.

Comment: I mentioned that in my comment @Andreas as well as updated my answer to give him necessary directions.

Answer (score 1):

You must increment `t` in this for loop:

```
for (int t = 0; t < phrase.length(); )
                if (CPUGuess == Character.valueOf(phrase.charAt(t)).toString()){
                    count++;
                }
```

Also, you are missing an open curly brace...It happens to the best of us. At the end, **with the increment and the curly brace:**

```
for (int t = 0; t < phrase.length(); t++ ) { //Need that curly brace!

                   if (CPUGuess == Character.valueOf(phrase.charAt(t)).toString()){
                        count++;

     } 
}

                //t++ Probably important...!
```

Comment: The `t++` needs to go in the `for` loop. If it's inside the `if` statement, it'll still loop forever.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, I know...It was a typo. I meant to add that as a comment, and also add it in the for loop. That's okay though, because I edited it. Thanks for your feedback though!

Comment: It does *not* need that curly brace, but if you do add it, you should add the matching end-brace too, or it won't compile.

Comment: @Andreas I put it. Thanks

Comment: But you do realize that adding the braces changes nothing, right? (except style)

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, and you could say the same about the if statement. But, it does keep the code more organized for later.

Comment: @Andreas can you elaborate more on **But you do realize that adding the braces changes nothing, right? (except style)**  how can we execute more than one line in a if condition without braces? Yes a loop or if condition do work without braces, that is not the point of my question.

Comment: @Raf I'm pretty sure it is because there is basiclly only one line. The one line is the if statement, and since that if statement has curly braces, the compiler takes it as **one statement.** Because, if you wanted, you can also right that if statement **in** one line anyway.   If my answer was of any help to you, I would really appreciate it if you liked my answer. If you have any more questions, feel free to ask me, I am happy to help!